# Django project using python 2.7 even though interpretor points to python version 3.5

Tags: python, django

My project interpretor points to python version 3.5.2:

`(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5)`

However when I go to the python shell in the project terminal (i'm using pycharm btw), it loads python 2.7. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the same virtual environment **PyCharm** is using when you develop your project.

So, lets say you have a configuration like this:

[image: PyCharm's project configuration]

Then you open the terminal and do:

```
$ cd ~/Documents/dev/
$ source ./pavorai-env-pycharm/bin/activate
$ NOW RUN YOUR DJANGO PROJECT
```

You should be using the same environment **PyCharm** is using. *Please do note that directory you are using WILL BE different than the one I am showing in this example*.

Comment: So should the environment be in my project directory? So is it not suitable to use `3.5.2 (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5)`?